# Why isn't GraphQL launching?

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

Could you explain to me why GraphQL does not launch?
I followed this tutorial: https://blog.devgenius.io/graphql-with-spring-boot-starter-graphql-7b406998c0b5

When I start the spring app I have no logs about Graphql...
No errors, nothing, so it's hard to know what's wrong.
My app starts well:
[image]

When I go on this url: http://localhost:8080/graphiql

I see this:

[image]

If I try to request this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/graphql' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"query":"query {\r\n  getAll {\r\n    id\r\n    title\r\n    author\r\n    content\r\n  }\r\n}","variables":{}}'
```

I have a 404 error:

[image]

Could you help me pls?

This is my schema:

[image]

query.graphqls:

```js
type Query {
    getById(id: String): Article,
    getAll: [Article],
    getAllByClient: [Article]
}

type Mutation {
    add(id: String, idClient: String): Article,
    update( title : String, category: String, content: String, planningTime: String): Article,
    publish(id: String): Boolean,
}
```

article.graphqls:

```js
type Article {
    id: String,
    title: String,
    category: String,
    content: String,
    planningTime: String,
    idClient: String,
    status: String
}
```

This is my controller:

```java
package org.qaravelle.technical.graphql;
...

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ArticleController {

    private final ArticleService articleService;

    private final ArticleMapper articleMapper = Mappers.getMapper(ArticleMapper.class);

    @MutationMapping
    public Article add(@Argument String id, @Argument String idClient) {
        try {
            return articleService.creerArticle(ArticleImpl.builder().id(UUID.fromString(id)).build());
        } catch (RuntimeException | ArticleNotInsertedException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public Article getById(@Argument String id) {
        try {
            Optional<Article> article = articleService.getById(UUID.fromString(id));
            if(article.isPresent()){
                return article.get();
            } else{
                return null;
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @MutationMapping
    public Article update(@Argument String title, @Argument String category, @Argument String content, @Argument String planningTime) {
        try {
            return articleService.updateArticle(articleMapper.toDomain(title, content, category, planningTime));
        } catch (RuntimeException | ArticleNotUpdatedException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public Iterable<Article> getAll() {
        try {
            return articleService.articles();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @MutationMapping
    public Boolean publish(@Argument String id) throws ArticleNotFoundException, ArticleNotUpdatedException {
        try {
            articleService.publish(UUID.fromString(id));
            return true;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public Iterable<Article> getAllByClient(@Argument String id) {
        try {
           return articleService.findByClient(UUID.fromString(id));
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    @SchemaMapping(typeName="Article", field="title")
    public String getTitle(Article article){
        return article.getTitle().getValue();
    }

    @SchemaMapping(typeName="Article", field="id")
    public String getId(Article article){ return article.getId().toString();}

    @SchemaMapping(typeName="Article", field="category")
    public String getCategory(Article article){ return article.getCategory().getValue().getValue();}

    @SchemaMapping(typeName="Article", field="planningTime")
    public String getPlanningTime(Article article){
        return article.getPlanningTime().getValue().toString();
    }

    @SchemaMapping(typeName="Article", field="idClient")
    public String getIdClient(Article article){
        return article.getIdClient().toString();
    }

    @SchemaMapping(typeName="Article", field="status")
    public String getStatus(Article article){
        return article.getStatus().getValue();
    }
}
```

I added this dependecies in my pom.xml:

```xml
<parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
    </parent>
...
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is currently fine, the error lies in the application startup. We don't do "mvn clean install" + IntelliJ startup of the main class. But rather, "mvn spring-boot:run".